# AWS API Gateway Overwriting Integration Request Mapping Template with the same parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I need to overwrite template by adding one new parameter.
But if I am adding something like this:

```
{
    "custom" : "param"
}
```

In my Lambda, I am getting just this parameter.
How I can overwrite template to pass existing parameters as is and add my sustom?
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm going to need more context. Cloudformation template. Openapi. Terraform. Mvce is missing. Thanks.

Comment: added few more screenshots